# Android OpenGl ES. Как нарисовать сферу и цилиндр?

Tags: java, android, opengl, графика, opengles

После поисков в гугле нашел следующие функции:

1. `gluSphere(...)`
2. `gluCylinder(...)`

Однако, эти функции не работают в ES, как я понял, в ES существует возможность рисовать только точки, линии и треугольники.

Я видел примеры, где рисуют куб: 6 граней, каждая из которых состоит из 2-х треугольников. Окружность, кольцо, прямоугольник со скругленными углами и все прочее рисуют так же из треугольников.

Я пришел к выводу, что сферу и цилиндр тоже следует рисовать из треугольников.

Для цилиндра:
Две окружности из `GL_TRIANGLES_FAN` - основания цилиндра, множество "узких" прямоугольников `GL_TRIANGLES_STRIP` - для боковой поверхности цилиндра - чем больше - тем красивее и менее производительно.

Для сферы: тут сложнее, думаю, можно сделать из множества квадратов `GL_TRIANGLES_STRIP` (по два треугольника на квадрат) - опять же чем таких квадратов больше, тем более гладкой должна получиться сфера.

Вопросов всего 2:

1. Является ли верным подход к рисованию 3D тел из простых треугольников или есть более правильный способ?
2. Возникнут ли проблемы при наложении текстур на такие тела, или как накладывать текстуры? :)

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

> Является ли верным подход к рисованию 3D тел из простых треугольников или есть более правильный способ?

учитая, что в вашем случае они будут рисоваться в смартфонах, в которых видеокарты не обладают большой производительностью по сравнению с десктопными, то треугольники это единственно верный вариант.

А вобще, кроме треугольников есть [ray tracing algorithms](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~hwshen/681/Site/Slides_files/basic_algo.pdf) (незнаю как на русский перевести) в основе которых лежит метод генерирации изображений при помощи испускания луча из точки наблюдения на сцену, и проверяя на пересечение каждого тела с этим лучом, например для сферы это выглядело бы так:

1. для каждого пикселя бросаем луч из точки наблюдения (из позиции камеры)
2. для каждого объекта из сцены находим точку пересечения с лучом
3. если точка ближайшая к камере вычисляем конечный цвет пикселя в этой точке

алгоритмы реализуются во фрагментном (или пиксельном) шейдере что требует большого количества вычислений, поэтому даже на десктопных машинах нужны большие вычислительные мощности, не говоря уже о смартфонах...

> Возникнут ли проблемы при наложении текстур на такие тела, или как
>   накладывать текстуры? :)

первая часть вопроса немного не корректна, так как проблемы конечно могут возникнуть если что то неправильно сделать.
касаемо второй части вопроса - грубо говоря, текстура накладывается при помощи текстурных координат, которые должны быть определены для каждой точки тела.
Точно также как и для остальных атрибутов вершины, под них выделяется буфер, или запихиваются в уже существующий буфер с остальными аттрибутами, читается изображение, связывается с этим буфером, далее отправляется вершинному шейдеру через который фрагментный получает тек координаты.

пример типичного вершинного и фрагметного шейдера для OpenGL ES

```
// vertex shader
precision highp float;

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vtexCoord;
varying vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 mvp;           

void main() {             
   gl_Position = mvp * vPosition;
   texCoord = vtexCoord;
}

// fragment shader
precision highp float;
varying vec2 texCoord;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texCoord);
}
```